# How to read the output of previous command and then proceed to the next command

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, tivoli

I wanted to write a script which will execute the next command only if the previous command was successful.

As part of the script I am trying to add files. Once the command to add the file is successfully executed, I get a message like as follows:

```
May 10, 2019 5:57:12 AM com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection findInitialEndpoint
INFO: CWWKX0230I: The collective member opened JMX client to the collective controller: ncr-aus-e171.corp.wayport.net:9081
May 10, 2019 5:57:12 AM com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection findInitialEndpoint
INFO: CWWKX0230I: The collective member opened JMX client to the collective controller: ncr-aus-e171.corp.wayport.net:9081
Successfully pushed policy to server
```

Once I receive the "Successfully pushed policy to server" message, I wanted the script to push the next file. (so on for 50 different files)

Can somebody let me know how to implement it?

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far? A sample of the current code?

Comment: @Bindu: What do you mean by "successfully executed"? Exit code zero?

Comment: Do you want somethng like `grep -q "Successfully pushed policy to server" && echo "Next command"`?

Comment: Yeah Walter grep for "Successfully pushed policy to server" message and execute the next command only if I receive the above message

Comment: @user1934428, successfully executed i mean if I have received "Successfully pushed policy to server" in the output of the command.

Comment: Then I suggest that you put this information into your posting,   because it is not obvious.

Comment: @Bindu: With "output" do you mean _standard output_ or does it also include _standard error_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
Commands=(
  "command1 parameter1 parameter2"
  "command2 parameter1"
  "command3 parameter1 parameter2 parameter3"
)

tmplog=$(mktemp)
for cmd in "${Commands[@]}"; do
   echo "$cmd"
   $cmd >"$tmplog"
   tail -1 "$tmplog" | grep -v "^Successfully" && break
done
rm "$tmplog"
```

Comment: If the command is going to take few seconds time to get executed, is there any means to wait until success message is received before picking the next command?

Comment: I tried sleep, but was getting lock unlock error between the commands.

Comment: Is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: I had the commands in an array:                                                                          
 for cmd in "${Commands[@]}"; do
   $cmd >"$policylog"
   sleep 50
   tail -1 "$policylog" | grep -v "^Successfully"
   i=`echo $?`
   if [[ $i == 0 ]]
   then
      echo "failed adding policy $cmd"
      exit
   else
      echo "successfully added policy $cmd"
   fi
done

Comment: Your grep command did not make sense. Becaust the parameter after the pattern must be a file name, and you are searching the word _Successfully_ in files with  the name  `i=`and `echo`. `grep`should have complained that it didn't find the files.

Comment: Sure grep looks in stdin too, but if you pass a file name, it looks ALSO for this file. For instance `echo abc|grep a xxx`fails if file xxx does not exist, although the standard input matches.